# Inmemory SQL DB options with support for analytic functions (parition over)?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite, in-memory-database

Working on adding unit testing around database code on a Java legacy project.  Some of SQL (Oracle) contains analytics functions .. (i.e. parition over syntax).  Is there any in memory SQL DB options out there (preferably open-source) that support these functions?

Any other solutions? I would prefer not to hit the real database (even if I rollback the data).

Answer (score 0):

Postgre SQL support window & analytic function. 
check the docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html)

you need to think if it's smart to test the data on a different platform though.

Comment: Can I easily configure Postgre for inmemory testing? (ala SQLLite)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, I would just spin up a local copy of Oracle XE because it is free.  This ensures that your test environment mirrors your production environment.  While it may be wise to use something like HyperSonic it is not a true representation of your production environment and as such some issues may be missed that could have been caught in test.